# how to set/get value to the custom field of a case in MS Dynamics CRM using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a requirement that i need to provide two contact fields for each case in MS Dynamics CRM.So i created a custom field " SecondaryContact "with dataType lookup(contact)for case(incident) entity in MS Dynamics CRM online.

now i want to pass value(contact id)from my appilication(in c#) to the custom field and also i want retrive all the cases based on custom field(contact Id)

### My code at present is to retrive all the cases based on PrimaryContactId

```
string primaryContactId = Session["ContactId"].ToString().Trim();
var context = new ForessCRMServiceContext(FssServiceProxy.orgService);
var result = from r in context.IncidentSet where r.PrimaryContactId.Equals(primaryContactId) orderby r.CreatedOn descending select r;
foreach (Incident incident in result)
 {
   dr["TICKETID"] = incident.TicketNumber;
   dr["SUBJECT"] = incident.Title;
   dr["STATUS"] = incident.StatusCode.Value;
   dr["ROWNUMBER"] = iRowNumber;
   dr["INCIDENTID"] = incident.IncidentId;
   dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

### }

### and iam creating case like this

```
string primaryContactId = Session["ContactId"].ToString();          
IOrganizationService _service = FssServiceProxy.orgService;
Entity incident = new Entity();
incident.LogicalName = "incident";

incident["title"] = txtSubject.Text.Trim();
incident["description"] = txtDescription.Text.Trim();
string AccountId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountId"]==null|| ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountId"].ToString().Trim().Equals("") ? "" : ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountId"].ToString().Trim();
Guid customerid = new Guid(AccountId);

EntityReference CustomerId = new EntityReference("account", customerid);
incident["customerid"] = CustomerId;
Guid contactid = new Guid(primaryContactId);
EntityReference EprimaryContactId = new EntityReference("contact", contactid);
incident["primarycontactid"] = EprimaryContactId;
Guid TicketID = _service.Create(incident);
```

i tried like below to retrieve the cases but iam getting error that " 'Incident' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'SecondaryContact'."

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
query.EntityName = "incident";
ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
cols.AddColumns(new string[] { "ticketnumber", "title", "statecode", "incidentid", "SecondaryContact"});
query.ColumnSet = cols;
RetrieveMultipleResponse retrived = new RetrieveMultipleResponse();
RetrieveMultipleRequest retrive = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
retrive.Query = query;
retrived = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)FssServiceProxy.orgService.Execute(retrive);
var result = retrived.Results;
```

Kindly advise me to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I always recommend using EarlyBound Entities, so you don't have any issues (Which is interesting in your case, since you've mixed and matched)  You can use the Early Bound Generator (https://github.com/daryllabar/DLaB.Xrm.XrmToolBoxTools/releases) to create the C# types for your custom fields...

Answer (score 0):

That means that incident entity doesn't contain field "SecondaryContact". To get this name you should open CRM customization, find incident entity, open it, check fields and field field that corresponds to SecondaryContact.

Answer (score 0):

This row will never work:

`cols.AddColumns(new string[] { "ticketnumber", "title", "statecode", "incidentid", "SecondaryContact"});`

This is because `SecondaryContact` as it is written will never work in CRM. You've created a custom attribute (per your question) and the logical name should be *prefix_logicalname*. When you configured the new attribute this name was created, likely something such as `new_secondarycontact`. That logical name is the one that needs to be in your code, in place of `SecondaryContact`.

Comment: Hi Nicknow, i tried as you mentioned but still i am getting the same error like
'Incident' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'new_SecondaryContact'.

Comment: What is the _logical name_ of the attribute in CRM? Please take a screenshot of the customization screen showing the logical name and add it to your questions (it should be all lowercase.) Btw, I recommend the suggestion from @Daryl to use his early-bound generator. It will create a `const` for each entity with these values (completely eliminating this problem.)